# Negative marginTop not working as intended on Android, works fine in iOS

Tags: android, react-native, layout, margin

Example of iOS and Android simulators.

[image]

Code:

```
<View style={styles.test}>
  <Text style={styles.header}>Header Example</Text>
  <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Text>
</View>
```

Styles:

```
test: {
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: "#000"
},
header: {
  marginTop: -10,
  backgroundColor: "yellow"
}
```

Anyone have some insight as to why this happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Negative margins do not work on Android because the default overflow is set to `hidden` on `<View>`.

The fix is to use the react-native-view-overflow library instead of `<View>`. That will allow you to use negative margins like you would expect.

https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow

```
yarn add react-native-view-overflow
```

Once added to your `package.json` file, you need to tweak your project a little for it to work.

In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

In `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
+        google()
     }
     dependencies {
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

And in order to remove warnings, in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
     compileSdkVersion 23
-    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
+    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
     defaultConfig {
```

---

Run `yarn run android` and you should be good to go.

[image]